# Passing array to -FilePath parameter in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, filepath, invoke-command

I'm using invoke-command to execute a list of scripts on remote servers.  I'm using a variable array to specify the scripts.

```
$Modules = Get-Content "Modules\Modules.txt"
$ModulePath = "Modules\" + $Module
Invoke-Command server -FilePath $ModulePath
```

This gives me an error:
Invoke-Command : The value of the FilePath parameter must be a Windows PowerShell script file. Enter the path to a file with a .ps1 file name extension and try the command again.
Parameter name: filePath

If I replace the array with the absolute path to an individual script file, it works without issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried outputting $ModulePath to see exactly what it is you're sending to that parameter?

Comment: I have.  The string output is the full path to the script file.

Answer (score 2):

No, it takes a single string only

```
-FilePath <String>
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try something like this:

Get-Content "Modules\Modules.txt" | foreach { invoke-Command "Modules\$_" }

Comment: Tried that with same results.  Interesting to note.  If I change $ModulePath to the full path of a single script it works. For example: $ModulePath = ".\Modules\Test.ps1"

Comment: Ok, that's right.  My bad there.  PowerShell will attempt to run from either its program folder or System32 (if in admin mode) if you don't specify the current dir.  Glad it's working for you.